# Doctrine and serialize data

Tags: php, doctrine

One of my column in database have serialize array of id's.
How I can properly get the name by id(after unserializing) in another table in doctrine?

Comment: And what have you tried?  Is this a question about how to write a `SELECT` statement?

Comment: I was tryed standart way by find($unserial_id) method and get the object but i think it is not a best way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of write a query based in the content of a serialized field.

You may need a [Many to many relation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional)

Comment: tnx
it will be not more than 3-4 id
is it a good idea create new table and set many to many?

Comment: If usually you'll do this kind of searchs the answer is yes